# Combine Cypress results for multiple environments as single run in Dashboard

Tags: cypress

Regarding the Cypress Dashboard and runs

We are running smoke and end-to-end tests post-deployment and the tests are run against multiple environments
Is it somehow possible to combine the results for all the environments into a single run in the Dashboard?

Current results as an example:

We run the smoke tests against 8 environments that have different configurations

- 7 of these environments are ok and are marked as a success
- 1 environment fails

If the run for the failed environment isn't the latest to be run the test in the Dashboard is green and we sometimes don't notice that something failed through the Dashboard

Technically they are all being run from the same commit id

Is there any command-line parameter that will combine this so that the Dashboard will look at this as the same run but just against different environments similar to how it does with browsers?

I've been going through the documentation and issues on GitHub but cant find anything related to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can construct a unique id and use the `--ci-build-id` passed to `cypress run` https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/command-line.html#cypress-run-ci-build-id-lt-id-gt

There is an example in the [Cypress Real World App](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2020/06/11/introducing-the-cypress-real-world-app/), [a payment application to demonstrate real-world usage of Cypress testing methods, patterns, and workflows](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-realworld-app), in the [Circle CI configuration](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-realworld-app/blob/develop/.circleci/config.yml#L75).  Note, this uses the Circle CI Orb syntax which maps to the `--ci-build-id` command line parameter.

Comment: Perfect, that pointed me in the right direction, "--ci-build-id" & "--group" was the correct combo. All smoketests run with the same --ci-build-id value and every smoketest runs with a unique --group value for example "smoketest-subdomain.domain.tld". Then they all get grouped under same run.

Comment: One gotcha, I had to go to "Project settings" in the Cypress Dashboard and set the "Run Completion Delay" to a higher timeperiod as the default is to close the test run after 60 seconds and not to allow new groups to be added to it after that.